# Streaming media from a download link

Tags: video, streaming

There often discussions and many facilities available to download streaming media (eg Youtube, Vimeo, etc), however is there a way it can stream a download link? Currently, my internet connection is prohibitively slow to download a video and I would prefer if I could watch the video while it is still downloading but I couldn't find how to do this. I did find this [article](http://www.engadget.com/2005/11/29/how-to-stream-almost-anything-using-vlc/) but it appears to need your own media server.

Comment: If you have slow internet, downloading, and watching at the same time may be very very bad as well. You will end up having the movie pausing every a couple of seconds waiting for the video to buffer up so they can play the next scene / seconds. You may be better off downloading them, and watching them after they finished downloading.

Comment: @Darius I agree but I'm more thinking of letting it buffer for 30 mins then watching it while the rest loads (rather than waiting ~2 hours for the whole file to download)

Comment: You do realize 30 minutes buffer may not means you can watch for 30 minutes. You may end up only watching for about 5 minutes and then the movie will hang again. Depends on how you download the movie, but one method is using Torrent and some Torrent client claims they can allow playing of the movie while it is being downloaded. You may even be able to try to simply play the movie using VLC even before it finishes downloading, but I can't say for sure whether it will be in a watchable condition or not, but sometimes VLC can attempt to play it even with an incomplete download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least some file formats [please edit if anyone knows which!] can be played in part before the download is complete.

If that doesn't work, it might be only because your downloader (e.g. Chrome) changes the file extensions to something like ".part" or whatever, which prevents your player from recognizing it. In that case, you might try copying and renaming the partially downloaded file.

If the video format is supported, some players will allow you to stream it by simply inputting the download URL in your player like you would a local file path. Have you tried [VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html)? If not, download that and try going to "Media" > "Open Network Stream..." and enter the download URL for the video you want to watch. (VLC also makes it fairly easy to serve a stream if you want to (see [the docs](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch02.html)).)

Finally I will echo points made in comments again here: 1) A slow connection means downloading is generally more advisable then streaming. 2) If the video you want is available by Torrent, clients like [Vuze](http://www.vuze.com/features/player) will stream it. A Torrent download will make the most of your slow connection compared to HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these instructions** (For the  best result use computer)

---

**Step 1.** Open the notepad or any text editor and paste the following code on that.

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <video src="Download link" controls></video>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Step 2.** Replace **Download link** with the actual download link.

**Step 3.** Now save this text as **html**

**Step 4.** Now open this html file and enjoy your show.

Comment: Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.

Comment: But how does the user *download* (i.e., save) the file while watching it?

Answer (score 0):

In Openload.co:
To convert stream link: https://openload.co/stream/somecodeshere
From Dowload Link, just replce the word "stream" to "f".
The DLink should be like this: https://openload.co/f/somecodeshere
Hope it helps.